# Rails geocoder attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes, controller, geocode

In the rails is it possible to make a function that everytime a particular attribute is changed, rails executes a function. In my case, everytime object.address (I have geocoded_by :address and after_validation :geocode) is changed, I want to do object.geocode. I am on rails 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution, I think would be to include ActiveModel::Dirty in your model, then you can check it in a callback

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def after_save
     if address_changed? do
       #some stuff..
     end
  end
end
```

see [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)

Answer (score 3):

Just pass the field to check for dirtiness in your after_validation as in

```
after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?
```

Comment: What if I want to check if 1 of 2 attributes have changed?

Comment: Simply make the symbol point to a method where you do the checking

Answer (score 0):

For me the most elegant solution is to use conditional validation based on whether or not the attribute to be geocoded_by (address) has changed.  You can do something like this in the "after_validation" callback of the model you are geocoding, or place it in whatever Active Record callback suits your purpose:

`after_validation :geocode, :if => lambda{ |obj| obj.address_changed?}`

Comment: What if I want to check if 1 of 2 attributes have changed?